# pass a variable over classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a bit of a scoping issue here i believe and would be grateful for any advice thanks

```
$variable_1 = 0

module Yogi
   class ErrorInside
     def yogify
      $variable_1 = new_value
     end
   end



  class CheckErrors
   def checker
    $variable_1 += 1
   end
  end
end
```

I would like $variable_1 to maintain the new value recieved in class ErrorInside and utilise it in the functions of class CheckErrors, but it sets them back to 0 as it seems.

Any advise on how to achieve that variable1 maintains the new value from class ErrorInside?

addition each class gets called in seperate executables so running class ErrorInside again before running class CheckErrors is out of question.

the idea is tho have the new value of $variable1 globaly available for all classes executed to a later stage

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort out how you name you classes, modules and definitions. Classes and modules take constants as their names and methods use [snake casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Then using the correct notation, call your methods after creating new instances of `Class1` and `Class2`.

```
$variable1 = 0

module Module1
  class Class1
    def method_1
      $variable1 = 10
    end
  end

  class Class2
    def method_1
      $variable1 +=  1
    end
  end
end

Module1::Class1.new.method_1
$variable1 #=> 10

Module1::Class2.new.method_1
$variable1 #=> 11
```

Comment: I urge anyone reading this answer to look at the original version of the question. OP changed their question (after I had posted certain recommendations) which now renders part of my answer obsolete.

Comment: tried to made it more need for people who didnt read about the issue...the issue is very simplified and its not the syntax, it  is the scoping what is the proplem i try to find a solution for. so i made it neat for the people hanging on the syntax things